# Display elements with JavaScript one by one and standing for a while depending on the length

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to display some text with JavaScript but only for some seconds depending on the length of the string. I've created a quite simple example based on the answers of the post [How to limit the number of iterations done by setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676331/how-to-limit-the-number-of-iterations-done-by-setinterval), but in my case does not work:

```
<script>
var iterations = 0,
    data = ['a','bbbbbbbb','c'],
    interval = setInterval(foo, 4000);

function foo() {
    console.log(data[iterations]);
    iterations++;
    if (iterations >= 4){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }else if(iterations == 1){
        //we want to make time longer in this iteration.
        clearInterval(interval);
        var interval = setInterval(foo, 8000);
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to take as output 'a' after 4 seconds, 'bbbbbbbb' after 8 and 'c' after 4 again.

As your can see I have an array with 3 elements. For iteration 1, it should wait for more time but does not. For all cases waits for 4 seconds and we have an infinite loop.

I've checked other functions like break does not work with `setInterval` function.

Would it be a smarter solution not based on for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring interval as a local variable inside 'foo'.

Change this code block from:

```
else if(iterations == 1){
    //we want to make time longer in this iteration.
    clearInterval(interval);
    var interval = setInterval(foo, 8000);
}
```

To this (no 'var' keyword):

```
else if(iterations == 1){
    //we want to make time longer in this iteration.
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(foo, 8000);
}
```