# limited number of dynamic generated images by using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanted to make a div of random positioned icons and this is what i made so far.
Can we make this to generate only limited number of images like 20 images and not unlimited.

If you have better way to make something like this, then i would be really thankful.

Thanks

```js
let nextId = 20

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        '//placekitten.com/200/200',
        '//placekitten.com/200/201',
        '//placekitten.com/200/202',
        '//placekitten.com/200/203',
        '//placekitten.com/200/204',
      ],
      addedImage: [],
      imgTop: -100,
      imgLeft: -100,
      imgHeight: 64,
      imgWidth: 64,
      changeInterval: 10,
      selectedImage: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.randomImage();
    const randomImg = func => setInterval(func, this.changeInterval);
    randomImg(this.randomImage);
    randomImg(this.addImage);
    randomImg(this.randomPosition);
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
      this.selectedImage = this.images[idx];
    },
    randomPosition() {
      const randomPos = twoSizes => Math.round(Math.random() * twoSizes);
      this.imgTop = randomPos(window.innerHeight - this.imgHeight);
      this.imgLeft = randomPos(window.innerWidth - this.imgWidth);
    },
    addImage(){
      this.addedImage.push({
        style: {
          top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
          left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
          height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
          width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
        },
        src: this.selectedImage,
        id: nextId++
        
      });
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :style="image.style" class="image" :key="image.id" :src="image.src" v-for="image in addedImage">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the number of iterations done by setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676331/how-to-limit-the-number-of-iterations-done-by-setinterval)

Comment: no i need working code as i also provided a code block. so i expect someone to help with real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce variables for the total, the current count, and the interval reference:

```js
limit: 20,
counter: 0,
interval: null
```

Combine the three calls to `setInterval` into one and store the interval.

```
created() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.randomImage();
    this.randomPosition();
    this.addImage();
    this.counter++;
    if (this.counter === this.limit) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }, this.changeInterval);
},
```

Each call increases the counter and when the limit is reached, the interval is cleared.  Here's a demo:

```js
let nextId = 20

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        '//placekitten.com/200/200',
        '//placekitten.com/200/201',
        '//placekitten.com/200/202',
        '//placekitten.com/200/203',
        '//placekitten.com/200/204',
      ],
      addedImage: [],
      imgTop: -100,
      imgLeft: -100,
      imgHeight: 64,
      imgWidth: 64,
      changeInterval: 10,
      selectedImage: '',
      limit: 20,
      counter: 0,
      interval: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.randomImage();
      this.randomPosition();
      this.addImage();
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter === this.limit) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }, this.changeInterval);
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
      this.selectedImage = this.images[idx];
    },
    randomPosition() {
      const randomPos = twoSizes => Math.round(Math.random() * twoSizes);
      this.imgTop = randomPos(window.innerHeight - this.imgHeight);
      this.imgLeft = randomPos(window.innerWidth - this.imgWidth);
    },
    addImage(){
      this.addedImage.push({
        style: {
          top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
          left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
          height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
          width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
        },
        src: this.selectedImage,
        id: nextId++
      });
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :style="image.style" class="image" :key="image.id" :src="image.src" v-for="image in addedImage">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a condition with a array length.

Length can be defined with any number of images we want. For example if we want 20 images then add this:

```
   addImage(){
        if (this.addedImage.length < 20) {
            this.addedImage.push({
                style: {
                    top: `${this.imgTop}vh`,
                    left: `${this.imgLeft}vw`,
                    height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
                    width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
                },
                src: this.selectedImage,
                id: nextId++

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: This way all of the intervals are still running and eating processor cycles

Comment: no it's not i already checked it.
iteration stops immedietly after 20 images.

Comment: This stops new objects from being created but since `clearInterval` was never called, the intervals are still running.  It's how it works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#Clearing_intervals